# Question for FeynRules: How to implement velocity dependent coupling

Tags: feyncalc

I am working with an extension of Standard Model which includes a fermionic field for the magnetic monopole. The photon-monopole coupling is velocity (beta = sqrt{1 - 4*monopoleMass^2/(s^2)} where sqrt{s} is center of mass energy) dependent. I included these blocks in my .fr file:

```
M$ClassesDescription = {
   V[1] == { 
        ClassName       -> A, 
        SelfConjugate   -> True,  
        Mass            -> 0,  
        Width           -> 0,  
        ParticleName    -> "a", 
        PDG             -> 22, 
        PropagatorLabel -> "a", 
        PropagatorType  -> W, 
        PropagatorArrow -> None,
        FullName        -> "Photon"
    },

    F[5] == {
        ClassName        -> MM,
        ClassMembers     -> {mm},
        Indices          -> {Index[Generation]},
        FlavorIndex      -> Generation,
        SelfConjugate    -> False,
        Mass             -> {MMM,1000},
        Width            -> 0,
        QuantumNumbers   -> {Q -> -1, LeptonNumber -> 1},
        PropagatorLabel  -> {"mm"},
        PropagatorType   -> Straight,
        PropagatorArrow  -> Forward,
        PDG              -> {410000},
        ParticleName     -> {"mm-"},
        AntiParticleName -> {"mm+"},
        FullName         -> {"Monopole"} 
        }
    }

    M$Parameters = {
        aEWM1 == { 
        ParameterType    -> External, 
        BlockName        -> SMINPUTS, 
        OrderBlock       -> 1, 
        Value            -> 127.9,
        InteractionOrder -> {QED,-2},
        Description      -> "Inverse of the EW coupling constant at the Z pole"
       },
   aEW == {
        ParameterType    -> Internal,
        Value            -> 1/aEWM1,
        InteractionOrder -> {QED,2},
        TeX              -> Subscript[\[Alpha], EW],
        Description      -> "Electroweak coupling contant"
       },
   GCH == {
       ParameterType    -> External,
       Value            -> Sqrt[Pi/aEW]
       InteractionOrder -> {QED,2},
       TeX              -> Subscript[G, CH], 
       Description      -> "Magnetic coupling constant"
    },

  shat == {
      ParameterType    -> External,
      Value            -> 13000.0,
      TeX              -> shat, 
      Description      -> "Center of Mass energy"
   }
   beta == {
      ParameterType    -> Internal,
      Value            -> (MMM*MMM)/(shat*shat),
      TeX              -> beta, 
      Description      -> "Mass over center of Mass energy"
    }

}
```

But when I import this model in Mathematica, I get this error:

```
ReplaceAll::reps :  {shat=={<<1>>}=={ParameterType->Internal,Value->MMM^2/shat^2,TeX->beta,Description->Mass over center of Mass energy}} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

My questions are the following:

1. How do I access the center of mass energy from the MadGraph5 run_card, rather than hard-coding the value in the M$Parameters?
2. I need a monopole velocity-dependent photon-monopole coupling. How can I achieve the same given that the velocity (i.e. beta) calculation needs the mass of the monopole (the MMM variable defined in the block F[5]) and the center of mass energy of the collision?

Thank you,
Arka

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You are missig a   ,    in between }  and  beta.